# 500 HTTP error on "Manage Display" tab after changing layout with Display Suite! What should I do?

Tags: 7, nodes, display-suite, entities

I changed the layout to "One column" with [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) on a given content type's "Manage display" tab, which has many (~30) fields. I'm also using [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module with multiple groups.
After saving, DS has set some group's parent elements to "Disabled". OK, I changed it, I dragged these to the enabled part, and after saving, I got a 500 HTTP-code when going to "Manage display" tab after a long waiting time!

What should I do? Can I simply uninstall Display Suite module? Will it reset the display to my original settings and field orders?

Thank you for any kind of ideas!

---

EDIT

**Uninstalling the module did NOT solve the problem**.... I'm in a real big trouble, because I don't know how to reset the display... 
Any ideas?

Comment: What does error log say?

Comment: @Ivanhoe123: possibly my live server is a piece of s***, because when going to `admin/reports/status`, I get an exception with this error message: http://pastebin.com/SZ5qxVHZ, but when testing it on localhost, it works fine. I don't understand, what can be wrong on the live server, if you have any kind of ideas, please share it, thanks. The `memory_limit` is set to 128 MB on the live server, which I think should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue, deleting the rows corresponding to my problamtic content type from the table "field_group" solved it. This way I didn't lose my entire field group settings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is a much better approach, so I accept your answer instead of mine. :) By the way, I think field_group module's solution for serializing all the data in one field is really ugly, maybe the developers haven't heard of database normalization... :) Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

OK, uninstalling the Field group module solved the problem. It seems like [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)  are not in a very good relation with each other... Maybe I'll post an issue related to the problem on drupal.org, because DS should be prepared not to "explode" a field_group, so each groups should stay together, and put to "Disabled" section together, or in no wise.

I think a possible solution until then could be that I create the new layout with Display Suite first, and **after that**, I create the field_groups, and take care that I don't move parent elements separately to "Disabled" section, because it can cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the message you posted is "MySQL server has gone away" which means that MySQL timeout limit was not enough (example: it waited too long for the server to respond).

You can change that the following way (basically you can replace 300 [5 mins] to any higher value you want):

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

This is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644572/1520477).

Check [this](http://drupal.org/node/259580) article and [this](http://bogdan.org.ua/2008/12/25/how-to-fix-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-2006.html) thread.

Comment: thanks, but does it really work in runtime? So if I put this in my index.php's beginning, does it really have an effect?

Comment: Yep. You can do either that or change mysql settings directly.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try this out in 10 minutes, and I'll give you a feedback! By the way, the original problem has been solved since then, but maybe this will be a cure for another time (e.g. for the same problem as the one above!).

Comment: I tried it, put both of the mentioned lines at the beginning of `index.php`, but unfortunately nothing has changed: I get the same _"2006 MySQL server has gone away: `SELECT * FROM {l10n_update_file}`; Array ( ) in `l10n_update_get_history()` (line 428 of /......./drupal/sites/all/modules/l10n_update/l10n_update.module)"_ exception when going to `admin/reports/status`. I would rather suspect the ridiculously low `max_allowed_packet = 1 048 576` to be the guilty one. Don't you think so? Anyway, I gave you a +1 for your helpfulness.